# Cannot resolve method startActionMode() while using Contextual Action Bar for a particular view

Tags: android, listview, contextual-action-bar, actionmode

I have been trying to use Contextual Action Bar on checkBox click to delete multiple rows from a listView... The listview has a checkbox and a textview in each row. In the adapter class, I'm calling startActionMode() as follows:

```
**@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder=null;
        View view=convertView;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
        final ToPayModel state = toPayList.get(position);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_pay_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvToPay);
            holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toPaycheck);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.name.setOnCheckedChangeListener();
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.check.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                ToPayModel toPayModel = (ToPayModel) cb.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                toPayModel.setCheck(cb.isChecked());
                if(state.isCheck()){
                    mActionMode=context.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallback());
                }
                else{
                    mActionMode.finish();
                }
            }
        });

        //holder.code.setText(" (" + state.getCode() + ")");
        holder.name.setText(state.getName());
        holder.check.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder.check.setChecked(state.isCheck());
        holder.check.setTag(state);
        return convertView;
    }
    public static final class ActionBarCallback implements ActionMode.Callback{
        public ActionBarCallback(){
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu,menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Checkbox Selected");
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.delete_item:
                   // removeSelection();
                    return true;
                default: return false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
             mode.finish();
        }
    }**
```

The Adapter class extends BaseAdapter

```
public class ToPayListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    static Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ActionMode mActionMode=null;
    public ArrayList<ToPayModel> toPayList;
    public ToPayListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ToPayModel> toPayList){

        this.context=context;
        this.toPayList=toPayList;


    }
```

But the problem is, there is an error when i call *startActionMode()*. It says cannot resolve the method. Is it because I'm calling from within the getView method...  I'm helpless... Any response will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `startActionMode`is defined for `Activity` but is not defined for `Context` (see [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActionMode(android.view.ActionMode.Callback))).

In your first chunk of code, if you are passing an `Activity` as the context, you can cast it to `Activity` as follows:

```
mActionMode=((Activity)context).startActionMode(new ActionBarCallback());
```

Or change the declaration

```
Context context;
```

to:

```
Activity context;
```

Edit from the comments:

If you are starting the `ActionMode.Callback` from a `View.OnClickListener()` in a `Fragment`, you can retrieve the the `Activity` this fragment is currently associated with using `getActivity()`:

```
YourFragmentClass.this.getActivity().startActionMode(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response..Actually the class i'm using extends Fragment... So would using ((Activity) context).startActionMode(new......)  work?

Comment: If your class extends `Fragment` then you can do `YourFragmentClass.this.getActivity().startActionMode(...);`

Comment: @antonio  Nice solution.  I have a RecyclerView list and am having trouble launching a Contextual Action Bar.  I would appreciate any help or insights you could provide on the issue, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406498/recyclerview-how-to-start-contextual-action-bar-cab-with-a-checkbox